# Reading the contents of a remote file without writing it locally

Tags: node.js, node-ssh

I am using `getFile()` to get a file from a server and this works fine.

But would it be possible to get *the contents* of a file on the server and put it in a variable instead of saving it first locally?

Comment: Which programming language are you talking about? How do you expect to get the content of a file without... getting the content of a file?

Comment: "... without writing it locally"

Comment: I am using node-ssh so javascript

Comment: You could remotely `cat` the file and work with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be a feature so I used @madflow 's advice and used execCommand and cat